# how i do this with java?

Tags: java, class

i have string contain the name of class which i need to define it ,

```
// this is the name of language class which i need to define it
String language = "english";
```

i can define it as :

```
english eng = new english();
```

but this method is for fixed names , but in my case , the string "language" may change to another class name , for example next time may be as :

```
String language = "french";
```

so i need to know a dynamic method to define the class of "language" string , to load any class with out using fixed method of defining such as :

```
french eng = new french();
```

Comment: This is not the "way of Java" and shouldn't be done, and there are better ways to carry this concept in Java as outlined below.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you shouldn't.

The quick solution is reflection. You can do `Class.forName(className)` and the class will be located (note that it should also include a package)

The better solution is to provide another mechanism for creation - factory, for example, and an interface common to all languages.:

```
interface Language { .. }

public class English implements Language { .. }
public class French implements Language { .. }

public class LanguageFactory {
     private static Map<String, Language> languageRegistry;
     public static Language createLanguage(String name) {
         return languageRegistry.get(name);
     }
     public synchronized void init() {
         //populate the registry
     }
}
```

(the registry is initialized once, by calling `.put("english", new English())`

Comment: I wouldn't want to use a mutable static.

Comment: It's not mutable. It is just lazy

Comment: It's both mutable and lazy. How are you claiming it's not mutable?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline oh, I've made it `public`, my bad. It was meant to be a sketch, without the lazy initializer. I'm making it private.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Language{
    String name;
    public Language(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

caller:

```
Language english = new Language("English");
```

But if you are not starting from scratch and the classes already exist, use reflection.